# Проблема с виджетом VK на сайте

Tags: php, javascript, html

Делается адаптивный сайт, и возник вопрос с виджетом VK комментарии: при ресайзе страницы не увеличивается размер самого виджета (он сейчас 300px). Порывшись в интернете, нашел решение данной проблемы (но только в консоли работает), на самом сайте в stylesheets.css она не работает, не пойму почему и как решить эту проблему?

```
    #vk_comments,
    #vk_comments iframe {
      width: 100%!important;
    }
```

и еще на сайте нашел как бы отвечающий за этот виджет скрипт/кодPHP (вносил изменения, но результат нет):

```
   //vkontakte
        $vkcomment='<script type="text/javascript"    src="http://userapi.com/js/api/openapi.js?29"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.init({apiId: '.$this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_apiid').',  onlyWidgets: true});
        </script>
        <div id="vk_comments"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        VK.Widgets.Comments("vk_comments", {limit: ';
           if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_kolvo')>=5)   $vkcomment.=$this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_kolvo'); else   $vkcomment.="5";
           $vkcomment.=', width: 300"';
           if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_shir')>=300)   $vkcomment.=$this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_shir'); else   $vkcomment.="300";
           $vkcomment.='", autoPublish:'.$this->config- >get('wp_vkcomment_autpub').', attach:';
           if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_graff')==1 && $this- >config->get('wp_vkcomment_photo')==1 && $this->config-  >get('wp_vkcomment_video')==1 && $this->config-  >get('wp_vkcomment_audio')==1 && $this->config-  >get('wp_vkcomment_silki')==1) $vkcomment.='"*"';
           else
              {
               $wpvkcommtmp=0;
            if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_graff')==1) {  $vkcomment.="\"graffiti"; $wpvkcommtmp=1;}
            if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_photo')==1) { if  ($wpvkcommtmp==1) $vkcomment.=",photo"; else { $vkcomment.="\"photo";  $wpvkcommtmp=1;} }
            if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_video')==1) { if  ($wpvkcommtmp==1) $vkcomment.=",video"; else { $vkcomment.="\"video";  $wpvkcommtmp=1;} }
            if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_audio')==1) { if ($wpvkcommtmp==1) $vkcomment.=",audio"; else { $vkcomment.="\"audio"; $wpvkcommtmp=1;} }
            if ($this->config->get('wp_vkcomment_silki')==1) { if ($wpvkcommtmp==1) $vkcomment.=",link"; else { $vkcomment.="\"link"; $wpvkcommtmp=1;} }
            if ($wpvkcommtmp==1) $vkcomment.="\""; else $vkcomment.="false";
               }
```

ссылка на [проект](http://adapt.uh-ty.com.ua/)

Answer (score 1):

Я конечно с WordPresso'm не сильно дружу. Но можно попробовать изменить здесь параметр: `$vkcomment.=', width: 300"';`
Но есть ещё один вариант, это переназначить свойство в самом css файле или между тегами  и  вставить тег  - в теле которого прописать свойство которе изменит ширину. Естественно делать это нужно после инициализации виджета. Так-же можно сделать блок отображения виджета дочерним!

Comment: это OpenCart, но спасибо за идеи. Насчет 300, уже менял, к сожалению ничего не происходит

Comment: wp_ - эта вставка как то смущает... видел такие в WordPress.